# HTML meta description: how many characters do engines display?

Tags: meta-tags

On Google, results are displayed with the meta description tag on one line, the description on the next, and the URL on the last.

How many characters of the meta description does Google display? I always thought it was around 150 or 160.

Answer (score 1):

Meta description tag provides short information on webpage as a summary. Meta description will not appear in web page but it display in Search Result Pages. Google search engine give much important to Meta Description Tag to display in search result pages, but yahoo and other related search engines give somewhat different important to meta description tag, so you should not neglect it altogether.
Meta Description Tag Length is not the number of words that count. It’s actually the number of characters length. Because, Google will cut off anything more than 155(roughly) characters. Optimizing for in the description and try to limit its length to 25-30 words. Also try to use no more than two sentences.